# Black screen and WHEA logger ID 18

Tags: windows, windows-8

My notebook (Acer Aspire 7520) is experiencing black screens (they happen every 20 minutes-1 hour) for which I have to manually reboot it and the system log says (I translated it from my IT log):

> Fatal hardware error.
>
> Signaled by the component: core processor Error Origin: Computer
>   Control Exception Error Type: Unknown Error Processor APIC ID: 1

Further data is available here:

> - System
>
>   - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger     [ Guid] 
>     {C26C4F3C-3F66-4E99-8F8A-39405CFED220} 
>      EventID 18 
>      Version 0 
>      Level 2 
>      Task 0 
>      Opcode 0 
>      Keywords 0x8000000000000000
>
>   - TimeCreated
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2013-04-11T15:53:47.254716200Z 
>      EventRecordID 2006
>
>   - Correlation
>
>   [ ActivityID]  {CB63F343-53AF-41F9-930A-CC226252421A}
>
>   - Execution
>
>   [ ProcessID]  1056     [ ThreadID]  1068 
>      Channel System 
>      Computer Alex-Mobile
>
>   - Security
>
>   [ UserID]  S-1-5-19
> - EventData
>
>   ErrorSource 3    ApicId 1    MCABank 2    MciStat 0xf600610000015311
>     MciAddr 0xc59b5b5f4d    MciMisc 0x0    ErrorType 256
>     TransactionType 256    Participation 256    RequestType 256    MemorIO
>     256    MemHierarchyLvl 256    Timeout 256    OperationType 256
>     Channel 256    Length 864    RawData
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

Sometimes there's another log warning that says: Event 19: hardware error corrected. By the way the screen remains black and I have to manually restart my pc.

What could be the cause? I'm using Windows 8 64 bit but freezes also happened with Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an actual hardware issue. Particularly since it occurs on two different operating systems.

Unplug all USB or other connected devices and monitor what happens. If you don't have anything connected regularly, then you should contact the hardware vendor to see if they have a diagnostics app you can run to test.  The most common issue will be with bad RAM, but that will usually manifest itself as a random blue screen instead of a black screen.